# Selenium - filter by font

Tags: python, css, selenium

I want to retrieve all text from "p" elements that match a particular font.

```
<p>
Hello there <i> mate </i> !
</p>
```

So, here, I want only "Hello there !" and not "mate". I already know the font (the whole css property) of "Hello there".

My current code is:

```
for elem in br.find_elements_by_tag_name('p'):
  if elem.value_of_css_property('font') == stored_font:
    snippets.append(elem.text)
```

but this also gives me all the italics. How can I recurse on all the children of the "p" and only get the text that matched my stored_font ?

Comment: You can't parse by font or font style but you can parse by tag. You would need to get the innerHTML of the `P` tag and then take out the tags (and contained text) that you don't want. Unless your HTML is really simple, it's going to get really complicated really fast.

Answer (score 0):

Using `set.difference()` seems appropriate here, assuming that your elements are unique:

```
p_tags = set(br.find_elements_by_tag_name('p'))
i_tags = set(br.find_elements_by_tag_name('i'))
p_tags_without_i_tags = p_tags.difference(i_tags)

for elem in br.find_elements_by_tag_name('p'):
  if elem.value_of_css_property('font') == stored_font:
    snippets.append(elem.text)
```

Comment: It's not always <i> tags, it can be other things that are not part of my style also. I want to recurse through everything and include it if the stored_font is the same.

Comment: Then you are going to need to write another conditional to check for the additional ways you are calling the font in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

We can get the text content of TextNode by javascript:

```
script = 'return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent + arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;';

for elem in br.find_elements_by_tag_name('p'):
  if elem.value_of_css_property('font') == stored_font:
    print driver.execute_script(script, elem);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have doubts about writing solution for filtering that stuff for test needs.
I would ethier assert all text with 'mate' or use `text.contains("Hello there")`